# How to insert brackets as text into HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append `<` and `>` signs within my variable using javascript but in browser it doesn't show up. If I append a String literal like `"Hi" + variableName` it works fine but not with the signs.I've tried it with single and double quotes both but no luck.

This was my attempt

```
document.getElementById("showInvalidEmailAddress").innerHTML = '<' + getEmailValue + '>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` so that the text doesn't get parsed as HTML.

```
const el = document.getElementById("showInvalidEmailAddress");
el.textContent = '<' + getEmailValue + '>';
```

The way you did it, the text looked like a tag to the HTML parser.

---

You can also use new template literals:

```
el.textContent = `<${getEmailValue}>`
```

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid HTML; an email address is not an HTML tag.

You mean `.textContent`.